# Make uploaded tmp file persists for the next request

Tags: php, file, persist, setting, tmp

IS it possible to make a tmp file (uploaded) persists for the next request?

Afaik,normally, it persists for only the current request, is here any php setting, php.ini setting or php method to achieve this

> without having to move or copy the tmp file somewhere

?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Only copy/move.

Comment: strange i dreamed it was possible  last night :D